# Duda pasar un icono desde ViewHolder a una actividad

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo un `reciclerView` con una lista y cada elemento es un `card_view` con información del tiempo, entre ellos un icono, todo eso me lo carga bien, en el onCreate del adapter he puesto un listener para que cuando se pulse un elemento de la vista, vaya a otra actividad para visualizar con mas detalle y mas información el tiempo de cada día, lo único que no puedo mandar por el intent es el icono (ImageView) para mostrarlo, todos los demás datos los envío bien.

Constructor `viewHolder`:

```
public ForecastItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.forecast_card);
    weatherIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sweather_icon);    
   day = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stext_view_card_day);
....................

....................

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ForecastItemViewHolder forecastItemViewHolder, int position) {
    final ForecastItem forecastItem = forecastItemList.get(position);
    forecastItemViewHolder.day.setText(forecastItem.day);
```

//esta funcion determina el icono que se muestra segun el valor de forecastItem.icom

```
setWeatherIcon (forecastItemViewHolder, forecastItem, forecastItem.icon);
```

la funcion de arriba hace la siguiente instrucción, según el valor de forecastItem.icon pone un icono u otro

```
forecastItemViewHolder.weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_01d)

.......

.......

}
```

El `oncreateView` que es donde llamo al show para ver el detalle de cada día, pero no se como recuperar el icono y tampoco como enviarlo en el intent, he probado con cosas como estas, pero no he conseguido nada:

```
Drawable iconD = forecastItemViewHolder.weatherIcon.getDrawable();

Bitmap icon = forecastItemViewHolder.weatherIcon.getDrawingCache();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", (Parcelable) iconD);
```

Este es el `oncreate` de la tarea Show para mostrar el detalle:

```
public ForecastItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.forecast_card, parent, false);
    final ForecastItemViewHolder forecastItemViewHolder = new ForecastItemViewHolder(view);


    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowForecastActivity.class);
            String day = forecastItemViewHolder.day.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("DAY", day);
           context.startActivity(intent);
                   .................

}
```

Este es el `oncreate` del show, aquí tampoco se como recuperar el icono en caso de que lo pudiera mandar por el intent.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_forecast);

    textViewValueDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_card_day);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
    String day = intent.getStringExtra("DAY");
    textViewValueDay.setText(day);
     ......................

}
```

Comment: ¿Tu icono esta dentro de tus recursos? es decir, en la carpeta drawable? Si es así lo puedes invocar de la misma manera en tu vista de detalle imageViewDetalle.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_01d)

Comment: Sí, pero por abreviar me he saltado una cosa en la explicación, el icono depende del tiempo por lo que es dinámico, tengo una función que dependiendo de un valor que devuelve una Api le pongo un icono u otro, ahora arreglo el post para aclararlo, entonces no sé el icono que es

Comment: Si tus iconos están dentro de tus recursos, no envies el icono envia el valor de forecastItem.icon en el intent y en el detalle recuperas dicho valor y vuelves a invocar a tu recurso .setImageResource()

Comment: Nose como hacer eso, porque en el onBindViewHolder es donde puedo acceder a los datos de elemento de mi lista con final ForecastItem forecastItem = forecastItemList.get(position); y de ahí sacar el icono, pero en el onCreate no tengo ni idea de como conseguir el string del icono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder pasar tu icono a tu detalle, debes crear una interfaz

import android.view.View;

```
  /**
   * A click listener for items.
   */
  public interface RecyclerOnItemClickListener {
      /**
       * Called when an item is clicked.
       *
       * @param childView View of the item that was clicked.
       * @param position  Position of the item that was clicked.
       */
      public void onItemClick( int position);
  }
```

Implementa esta interfaz en tu actividad y sobreescribes el método

@Override
    public void onItemClick( int position)
    {

```
    ForecastItem forecastItem = forecastItemList.get(position);
    //Aqui recuperas a la cadena de tu icono y lo envias en el intent hacia tu    detalle
}
```

Inicializa el listener en el constructor de tu adapter

mItemClickListener = recyclerOnItemClickListener;

En tu viewHolder implementa al onClickListener y pasale el valor listener al view que quieras que tenga el evento, por ejemplo

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

```
View rootView;


public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    rootView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    rootView.setOnClickListener(mItemClickListener);

}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (mItemClickListener != null)
        {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick( getPosition());
        }
    }
```

}

De esta manera puedes obtener tu objeto ForecastItem en tu activity y obtener la información que necesites.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido